# Two Javascript Scripts Will Not Function Together (Snow.js & Countdown.js)

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a X-Mas Countdown and two of my scripts won't work together. I can't find what is wrong. I believe something is repeated but I can't see it, hopefully one of you catches it. Which ever script is 2nd is the one that works. It is not the z-index: (or should not be) as that functions with the text apart from the countdown. The snow does not appear on the canvas until the countdown code is removed or comes first.

```js
/* Countdown */

function updateTimer(deadline){
  var time = deadline - new Date();
  return {
    'days': Math.floor( time/(1000*60*60*24) ),
    'hours': Math.floor( (time/(1000*60*60)) % 24 ),
    'minutes': Math.floor( (time/1000/60) % 60 ),
    'seconds': Math.floor( (time/1000) % 60 ),
    'total' : time
  };
}


function animateClock(span){
  span.className = "turn";
  setTimeout(function(){
    span.className = "";
  },700);
}

function startTimer(id, deadline){
  var timerInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = updateTimer(deadline);

    clock.innerHTML = '<span>' + timer.days + '</span>'
                    + '<span>' + timer.hours + '</span>'
                    + '<span>' + timer.minutes + '</span>'
                    + '<span>' + timer.seconds + '</span>';

    //animations
    var spans = clock.getElementsByTagName("span");
    animateClock(spans[3]);
    if(timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[2]);
    if(timer.minutes == 59 && timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[1]);
    if(timer.hours == 23 && timer.minutes == 59 && timer.seconds == 59) animateClock(spans[0]);

    //check for end of timer
    if(timer.total < 1){
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      clock.innerHTML = '<span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>0</span>';
    }


  }, 1000);
}


window.onload = function(){
  var deadline = new Date("December 25, 2018");
  startTimer("clock", deadline);
};

/* Snow */

window.onload = function(){
    var canvas =  document.getElementById("sky");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    var W = window.innerWidth;
    var H = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = W;
    canvas.height = H;

    var mf = 100;
    var flakes = [];

    for(var i= 0; i < mf; i++){
        flakes.push({
            x: Math.random()*W,
            y: Math.random()*H,
            r: Math.random()*5+2,
            d: Math.random()* + 1
        })
    }
    
    function drawFlakes(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
            var f = flakes[i];
            ctx.moveTo(f.x, f.y);
            ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        }
        ctx.fill();
        moveFlakes();
    }
    var angle = 0;

    function moveFlakes(){
        angle += 0.01;
        for(var i = 0; i < mf; i++){
            var f = flakes[i];
            
            f.y += Math.pow(f.d, 2) + 1;
            f.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;

            if(f.y > H){
                flakes[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: 0, r: f.r, d: f.d};
            }
        }
    }
    setInterval(drawFlakes, 25);
}
```

Comment: You are setting `window.onload` and then immediately setting it to something else. Do you expect both to run on load?

Comment: Mark is correct, and further for your understanding, the `.onload` property can only contain one value at a time. The proper way to accomplish your goal is by using `window.addEventListener(...)` which allows multiple functions to run as a result of an event.

Comment: How would I go about this? I have tried useing eventlistner however I can't seem to use it, what would you do?

Comment: @MtnBros - Have you not seen the following in javascript before? `window.addEventListener('load', someFunctionName, false);` Adding to what Mark said, you could call the line several times with different functions to be called after the event is fired.